# useQueryClient isn't defined

Tags: react-query

Pretty simple. We're using `"react-query": "^2.26.1"`, and when I try this, from the v2 docs:

```js
 import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
```

it doesn't recognize it as existing.

Indeed, `node_modules/react-query/types/react/index.d.ts` doesn't have it:

```
export { ReactQueryCacheProvider, useQueryCache, } from './ReactQueryCacheProvider';
export { ReactQueryConfigProvider } from './ReactQueryConfigProvider';
export { ReactQueryErrorResetBoundary, useErrorResetBoundary, } from './ReactQueryErrorResetBoundary';
export { useIsFetching } from './useIsFetching';
export { useMutation } from './useMutation';
export { useQuery } from './useQuery';
export { usePaginatedQuery } from './usePaginatedQuery';
export { useInfiniteQuery } from './useInfiniteQuery';
export { UseQueryObjectConfig } from './useQuery';
export { UseInfiniteQueryObjectConfig } from './useInfiniteQuery';
export { UsePaginatedQueryObjectConfig } from './usePaginatedQuery';
export { ReactQueryCacheProviderProps } from './ReactQueryCacheProvider';
export { ReactQueryConfigProviderProps } from './ReactQueryConfigProvider';
export { ReactQueryErrorResetBoundaryProps } from './ReactQueryErrorResetBoundary';
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The v2 docs incorrectly show v3 content. `useQueryClient` doesn't exist in v2.

The best way to consume the v2 docs would be here:

https://github.com/TanStack/query/tree/v2.26.4/docs/src/pages

However, please keep in mind that the last v2 release was pretty much 2 years ago (2020-12-07) is not actively maintained. v4 is the latest version (available under `@tanstack/react-query`), and work on v5 will start soon

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4